# my text does not show inside absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

My text doesn't show inside absolute positioned div. Some of them show but some of them don't. The divs are positioned absolute
and the styles are the same but I don't know why it doesn't show.

```css
.shapeContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.shape {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 255px;
  background: rgb(0, 31, 255);
  background: linear-gradient( 135deg, rgba(0, 31, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 44, 119, 1) 27%);
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 78.51%, 25.42% 78.51%, 27.25% 53.71%, 22.74% 53.71%, 18.92% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.shape2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 79.67%, 24.85% 79.67%, 26.55% 55.28%, 22.88% 55.28%, 19.06% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.shape3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 265px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 44, 119, 1);
  clip-path: polygon( 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80.95%, 24.15% 80.95%, 25.98% 57.14%, 23.02% 57.14%, 19.35% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.shape4 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  background-color: #004be2;
}

.shape5 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 255px;
  background-color: #002157;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 25% 0, 18% 92%, 0 92%);
}

.shape6 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #0c00e0;
  clip-path: polygon(47% 19%, 100% 19%, 100% 72%, 42% 72%);
}

.shape7 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #00001a;
  opacity: 0.5;
  clip-path: polygon(56% 0, 100% 0, 100% 47%, 52% 47%);
}

.shape8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -45px;
  z-index: 7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00001a;
  opacity: 0.5;
  clip-path: polygon(32.19% 61.15%, 38.25% 61.15%, 37.3% 90%, 31.26% 90%);
}

.shape9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00001a;
  opacity: 0.5;
  clip-path: polygon(32.19% 61.15%, 38.25% 61.15%, 37.3% 90%, 31.26% 90%);
}
```

```html
<header className="header">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="shapeContainer">
      <div className="shape">shape8 1</div>
      <div className="shape2"> shape 2</div>
      <div className="shape3">shape 3</div>
      <div className="shape4">shape 4</div>
      <div className="shape5">shape5 </div>
      <div className="shape6">shape6</div>
      <div className="shape7">shape 7</div>
      <a href="#" className="shape8">
              shape8
            </a>
      <a href="#" className="shape9 ">
              shape9
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Text is overlapping due to  position and z-index. can you share the output image. className is working in reactJs. If you are not using. please change it from className to class.

Comment: yes it's in React. sorry i forgot about that
i will share the image hold on..but what can i do about the overlapping

Comment: this is the output

https://o.sha.tel/s_mohammadiha/20220124-194409-7hO5pKCz.png

Answer (score 3):

You are using 'classname' atribute, change it for just 'class' in your HTML file. It will work!

**Right code below**

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shapeContainer">
                <div class="shape">shape8 1</div>
                <div class="shape2">shape 2</div>
                <div class="shape3">shape 3</div>
                <div class="shape4">shape 4</div>
                <div class="shape5">shape5</div>
                <div class="shape6">shape6</div>
                <div class="shape7">shape 7</div>
                <a href="#" class="shape8">
                    shape8
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="shape9">
                    shape9
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: its not working. I cannot see the text 7, 8 and 9..

Comment: i am using className because it is a React Component
sorry i forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

The path cut of everything positioned out of the shape you draw. The text is still in the top left corner of div but cut off.

I guess there are more solutions.

**I would use one more tag to wrap the text into. Than I would position it to the place I need via `position:absolute;`.**

There is possibly more proper way to do it - change size of div to the size of shape you want and than draw the path in that container. Move it via position absolute. Text would still be in the top left corner, but easily moved by in wrapper div.

```css
.shapeContainer {
    position: relative;
  }  
  
 .shape5 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    background-color: red;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 25% 0, 18% 92%, 0 92%);
  }
 .textInShape{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 20px;
    color: aliceblue;
} 

.shape7 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 50%; 
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 82%, 44% 82%); /*changed size of div and path*/
  }
   .textInShape2 {
      position: absolute;
      color: aliceblue;
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center; 
/*if you dont mind exact position, u can also align the text to middle in this case*/
  }
```

```html
<header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="shapeContainer">

          <div href="#" class="shape5">
            <div class="textInShape">shape5</div> 
           </div>
          <div class="shape7">
            <a href="#" class="textInShape2">HALLOOO</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```